# Why do I have TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null with GET REST API?

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose

This is the comment from comments collection(MongoDB) that I am trying to retrieve.
[image]

My getComment method

```
// @route     GET /api/v1/Comments/:id
exports.getComment = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const comment = await Comment.findById(req.params.id);

  if (!Comment) {
    return next(
      new ErrorResponse(`No Comment found with the id of ${req.params.id}`, 404),
    );
  }

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    data: comment,
  });
});
```

I am using POSTMAN,when I try

```
GET localhost:5000/api/v1/comments/5fce5d6c9ead51271d7c4160
```

I got typeerror

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

Postman response

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;1&#39; of null<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at firstchar
```

My Comments model

```
const Comment = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  body: String,
  postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  },
  blog: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'BlogPost',
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

Adding comment works fine

```
POST localhost:5000/api/v1/comments/5fc5294add045b2ece2595b9
```

Id in this case refers to Blogpost

```
// @route  POST /api/v1/blogpost/:blogid/comment
exports.addComment = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  req.body.blog = req.params.id;
  req.body.postedBy = req.user.id;

  const post = await BlogPost.findById(req.params.id);
  const comment = await Comment.create(req.body);
  console.log(comment);
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    data: comment,
  });
```

EDIT
This works

```
GET localhost:5000/api/v1/comments/5fce5d6c9ead51271d7c4160
```

with JSON body

```
{
    "title": "whatever",
    "body" : "pich"
}
```

Got the right response.

```
"success": true,
"data": {
    "_id": "5fce5d6c9ead51271d7c4160",
    "title": "Ola,de novo!",
    "body": "Avenida Jovia,morava la antes,priquita!",
    "blog": "5fc611f3b1b10346cd1ed538",
    "postedBy": "5fc4bc019a141602fb78d0b5",
    "createdAt": "2020-12-07T16:50:52.024Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I am still confused,it seems that body can not be empty.

Why?

Comment: Could you paste the error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a typo on `if (!Comment)`

It should be

```
  if (!comment) { // notice lowercase "c"
    return next(
      new ErrorResponse(`No Comment found with the id of ${req.params.id}`, 404),
    );
  }
```